# How to open menu item on click on RecyclerView Row

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, bottomnavigationview

I have an app with `BottomNavigationView`, which has 2 menu items. Both have their `Fragments`. On the first item in the `Fragment` I have a `RecyclerView`. I want to open the second menu item on click on `RecyclerView` row and also send some parameters. How and where should I do it?

What am I doing now:
In the `Fragment`, which I show on the first menu item, I have a method, that I pass to `RecyclerViewAdapter`, so that it can be triggered each time a row is tapped. But I cannot find any method in my `listener as BottomNavActivity` to open it's second menu item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From API 25.3.0 it was introduced the method `setSelectedItemId(int id)` which let's you mark an item as selected as if it was tapped.

From docs:

> Set the selected menu item ID. This behaves the same as tapping on an
>   item.

Code example:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.my_menu_item_id);
```

For those, who still use SupportLibrary < 25.3.0

```
View view = bottomNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.menu_action_item);
view.performClick();
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. My problem was that I didn't differentiate `BottomNavActivity` & `BottomNavigationView`. Just tried to access `setSelectedItemId()` in the first one instead of the second. Thanks once more!

Comment: But what about passing some data? Is there a proper way to do that? I see for now only one approach - creating a singleton, so that it's accessible from both tabs. But maybe there is a better way? I'd appreciate some advice, thanks in advance!

Comment: This does not handle optionals and is likely to crash. Given that the answer is in Java it should be wrapped in an if statement that checks for != null

Answer (score 1):

You need a reference to your activity within the adapter. You can pass this in during initialisation using

```
SomeAdapter(var activity: Activity)
```

Then inside your adapter you set the onClickListener with the following action

```
activity?.navigation?.selectedItemId = R.id.navigation_id_here
```

Comment: Cool, this works, but I've no intent to pass `Activity` to `Adapter`. The `selectedItemId = R.id.navigation_id_here` was really helpful though, thank you!

Comment: No probs, the activity will help you avoid non optional views. You can also use the same pattern to pass data into your adapater :)